# Print array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

I want to print an array of objects of two classes. I have class student as `Base` class, and `CS_student`, `IS_student` derived classes, and I have an array of type student and I want to print it in the print function of class university.

I want 3 options:

1. print all CS_student .
2. print all IS_student .
3. print all CS_student and IS_student.

But it print only one object. Here's my code

```
class student (){
int ID;
string first_Name;
string last_Name;

public:
virtual void print ()=0; };

class CS_student ():public student {

public:
    void print(){
        cout<<" CS student "<<endl;}
};
class IS_student():public student {

public:
    void print(){
        cout<<"IS student"<<endl;}
};
class university {
    student **S;
    int size;
public :
    university (){
        S= new student *[size];
        size = 10;}
        ........
        ........

        void Print(){
            int y;
            cout<<"enter 1 to print CS student , enter 2 to print IS 
    student , enter 3 to print all CS and IS students";
            cin>>y;
            switch(y){
                case 1:{
                    for ( int i =0 ; i<size ; i++){
                      student * obj = S[i];
                      CS_student *obj2 = dynamic_cast<CS_student*>(obj);
                      if(obj2){
                     obj2->print();}
                    }
                       }
                       break;
                case 2:{
                    for ( int i =0 ; i<size ; i++){
                      student * obj = S[i];
                      IS_student *obj2 = dynamic_cast<IS_student*>(obj);
                      if(obj2){
                     obj2->print();}
                    }
                       }
                       break;
                case 3:{
                    for ( int i =0 ; i<size ; i++){
                       S[i]->print();}
                    break;
                default:{
                    cout<<"Error";
                        }
                       }
            }
        }
};
```

Comment: You seem not to be familiar with the concept of "sequence". But intuitively, what do you think `S = new student *[size]; size = 10;` does?

Comment: What happens if you omit the `if(obj2){...}` checks? Does it crash? Then I assume you have nullpointers in your array.

Comment: @UliKöhler yes it crash

Comment: That means you've got a problem with your initialization. Crash (usually) means a NULL ptr (assuming it crashes with SIGSEGV). That means you leave some students uninitialized --> the student* is a pointer that doesn't point to a valid memory location. The problems seems to be in your initialization code which isn't shown in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You're initializing `S= new student *[size];` before you're setting `size=10`. You should initialize the `size` variable before using it.

Comment: Does omitting the `if(obj2){...}` checks crash the program? Is there any specific reason why you introuced them?

Comment: @RaiOu Did this fix your issues?

Answer (score 0):

```
S= new student *[size];
size = 10;
```

So you use `size` as the length of the dynamically allocated array, and then you set size to `10`. So what size is the array? Well when you used it, it was uninitialized and using it had undefined behaviour. You need to swap these two lines around so that `size` is `10` when you create the array.

Comment: size = 10 ; is typo , i sent the size from the main when i create the objects , i didn't write all methods , but it works well .. only the print